# How to increment a value in Firebase Realtime Database using HTML onclick function for link "<a>" tag

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to read a value from the firebase realtime database and then update the value by incrementing it with 1 and then update it again on the firebase realtime database.

The javascript function is attached to a HTML  tag.

```
<div>
     <a href="#" onclick="return LikeButton();">Link</a> <br><br>
</div>
```

In the image below, I want to update the value of **Clicks** by incrementing +1 everytime I click on the link inside the  tag.

[image: intended value]

Here is the full code - [clicks_count.html](https://github.com/nilutpolkashyap/firebase_projects/blob/main/firebase-html-js/clicks_count.html)

I tried to first read the database using the **get()** function and then use the **update()** function to update the data aftering incrementing the read value by **+1**.

```
function LikeButton() {
    const dbref = ref(db);

    get(child(dbref, "Blogs/001/")).then((snapshot)=>{
        if(snapshot.exists()){
            var val = snapshot.val().Clicks;
            update(ref(db, "Blogs/001"),{
                Clicks: Number(val) + 1,
            })
            .then(()=>{
                alert("data enter successful");
            })
            .catch((error)=>{
                alert("unsuccessful, error="+error);
            });
        }
        else{
            alert("No data found");
        }
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
        alert("unsuccessful, error="+error);
    });
}
```

### Updates

I instead created a HTML button to work with my function and removed the link "" tags. I used the **window.open()** to open the link.

```
<button id="linkcntrbtn"> UPDATE </button>
```

Here's the JS function snippet

```
function LinkCounterButton() {
    const dbref = ref(db);

    get(child(dbref, "Blogs/001/")).then((snapshot)=>{
        if(snapshot.exists()){
            clicksbox.value = Number(snapshot.val().Link01Count) + 1;
            var val = snapshot.val().Link01Count;
            update(ref(db, "Blogs/001"),{
                Link01Count: Number(val) + 1,
            })
            .catch((error)=>{
                alert("unsuccessful, error="+error);
            });
            window.open("https://www.google.com", "_parent");
        }
        else{
            alert("No data found");
        }
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
        alert("unsuccessful, error="+error);
    });
    return true;
}
linkcntrbtn.addEventListener('click', LinkCounterButton);
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you're not using the atomic increment operation shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#atomic_server-side_increments? --- Also: you're writing to `update(ref(db, "Articles/001/"),{`, but the screenshot shows (and the code *reads): from `/Blogs/001`. Are those supposed t be the same?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for your reply. I am new to using Firebase realtime database with HTML and javascript. I will look into the atomic operations.
It was supposed to be "/Blogs/001". I edited it now.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen My javascript function seems to work with a button tag. I already tested it and it works. But I want to make it work with HTML <a href=""> tags everytime the link is clicked, the value gets incremented.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your page navigates away before it has a change to write to the database. That's because the `onclick` handler on an `a` tag has no knowledge of the asynchronous operation you're performing.

Instead of returning the result of the `LikeButton` call (which is `undefined`), return a hard-coded value of `false` right away to prevent the page from navigating:

```
<a href="#" onclick="LikeButton(); return false">Link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was still not able to work with the above so I instead created a button tag and attached a JS function to it. 
I updated the code snippet in the description above.

Comment: I had to specify the "website url" inside window.open in my function and also I am updating the value of "Link01Count" key for a particular button. So if I have multiple buttons , how can I pass the website URL and the "key" to update in firebase as arguments
I don't want to have multiple functions for each button I have in my page.

Comment: Good to hear you got it working @NilutpolKashyap!  --- Can you post the solution as an answer? That allows you to then accept it (after a few hours), which makes it clear to the system you've been helped, makes it easier for others to find the solution - and allows folks to then upvote your answer. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer